# SoapUI-PRO with allure reporting - Maven build throws error - Could not find artifact ru.yandex.qatools.allure

Tags: maven, soapui, allure

I'm using maven build projects to execute Soapui-Pro tests. I am trying to see if Allure can be used to generate reports. But it throws error. Please let me know what seems to be the problem.

> Error "Could not find artifact ru.yandex.qatools.allure"

My POM file looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.smartbear.soapuiMavenTutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>SoapUI-Maven-Tutorial</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SoapUI-Maven-Tutorial</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
         <aspectj.version>1.8.6</aspectj.version>
        <allure.version>1.4.14</allure.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId> 
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
              <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version> 
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <modules>
        <module>PRO-MAY-ER-TestSuite</module>
        <module>ErrorCodes-TestSuite</module>
    </modules>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>SmartBearPluginRepository</id>
            <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
                        <version>10.2.0</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                        <!--systemPath>C:\maven\ojdbc6.jar</systemPath-->
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <groupId>com.smartbear</groupId>
                <artifactId>ready-api-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

That version of `allure-maven-plugin` does not exist at [Maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22ru.yandex.qatools.allure%22%20AND%20a%3A%22allure-maven-plugin%22). Pick another version from that list; version 2.2 seems to be the latest.

Alternately, if you need the snapshot version, you will need to specify a repository that has that version; perhaps [here](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-maven-plugin).